# dynamically storing runtime variables in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to port my PC-app to android. I am not sure how I should handle the variables: 
There are several notes, each of them has text, title, color and so on. I need to read and write them from/to a file; But I can't use json because I have already serialized the notes by hand in my PC-application.

I thought about reading a file inputstream and writing to an outstream. But internally at runtime, how can I store them, perhaps in a way like

```
notes = [ [note1_text = text1, note1_title = title1, ...] , [note2_text, note2_title, ...] ]
```

where

```
text1 = <Doctype .. html >
title = "a note"
```

and so? I don't know so much about Java, coming from C++ and Qt.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is your asking. Do you just need a way to group the text, title, color (etc.) variables together?

Comment: Yes somehow like this. Sorry for being unclear. I need to find a way to clearly tell which TextView is associated with the right properties. It is so that there are probably less TextViews than notes, but I need to pass a note's content into the right textView each time it is shown. How to do that since the variables are no "real members" of a note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a class to hold the information, like so:

```
public class Note {

    private String title;
    private String text;
    private String color;

    public Note(String title, String text, String color) {
        this.title = title;
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the notes like so:

```
Note noteA = new Note("My Title", "Here is my text", "#FF00FF");
Note noteB = new Note("Another title", "Here is some more text", "#0000FF");

noteA.getTitle(); // Will return 'My Title'
```